infinite loop while using new `use` hook in react
I am trying to use new use API. The code to reander the page looks like this
const loadData = async (tenant_id: string, project_id: string) => {
    const response = await  findProject(tenant_id , project_id,)
    if ('code' in response) {
        return response as ApiError
    }
    const prj = response as Project
    return prj
}
export const ProjectForm = ()=> {
    const profile = gstate.use.profile()
    const routeParams = useParams();

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <ProjectHolder project_promise={loadData(profile!.tenant_id!, routeParams.project_id!)} />
        </Suspense>
    );
}
function ProjectHolder({project_promise}: {project_promise: Promise<Project | ApiError>}) {
    const project_maybe = use(project_promise)
    return <div> project component</div>
}

The detail of component in projectHolder doesn't really matter.
The problem is as follows. The first time I navigate to a url that shows this component - like http://localhost:5173/projects/b0098906-4e16-4c74-bb2e-62805feb1e32 , every thing is fine, it renders and fetches properly.
But when I navigate to a second page, while on that page, it calls loadData in a loop.
This component is rendered inside a template using react-router.

show the parent component that uses this code.  if the call for data works initially as expected and loops only on subsequent attempts, i'd be suspicious that the problem lies in the caller, not how the call is handled.  unless the call is returning an error (unrelated to the infinite loop), but i assume you would have mentioned that.

The component is a whole page really, inside a template, and used by react-router.

I'll be honest and say that project_promise={loadData(profile!.tenant_id!, routeParams.project_id!)} seems quite wrong; you don't generally unconditionally call a function prop like this unless it's a curried function, e.g. a function that returns the callback function. When doing this any time ProjectForm is rendered for any reason the loadData function will be called. We need to see a more complete [mcve].
